# Can the Xero accounting package be integrated with CiviCRM?

Tags: accounting

What degree of integration is there between [Xero](http://xero.com) and CiviCRM?

Comment: Does anyone know of any organisations that use the Civi Xero extension

Comment: Yes - we have half a dozen or so clients using it.

Answer (score 4):

There has been some integration work undertaken by Fuzion and is available in this [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civixero). General functionality:

- create contacts in Xero based on them being created (or having had a contribution or recurring contribution) created in CiviCRM. You can configure which of those 3 will cause them to be created in Xero
- update contacts in Xero based on the contact or contact details having been updated in CiviCRM
- adds a link to the contact summary to the Xero record
- adds a link from the contact summary to the contact's transaction history in Xero
- creates invoices in Xero based on contributions in CiviCRM (and adds a link in CiviCRM)
- where a pending contribution has a payment matched in Xero the CiviCRM contribution is updated (which participant records, memberships etc also being updated & emails sent as configured)
- where a contribution is voided or cancelled in Xero it can also be cancelled in CiviCRM

The [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civixero) cannot be downloaded through the UI (intentionally) as it defintely requires someone technically savy to be involved in setting it up & maintaining it. You can see much of what is possible at this [blog post](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/civicrm-integration-xero)